# How to write unit test for function returning time after one hour

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have the following function which adds given number of hours in current time and returns new time in a

```
func getExpiryTime(hour int) *string {
   const layout = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z"
   expiryTime := time.Now().Local().Add(time.Hour *time.Duration(hour))
   return aws.String(expiryTime.Format(layout))
}
```

What would be the best way to write unit test for this function?

Comment: You can't really test something that's based on the current clock time. It would have to accept the original time as a parameter, to which you could pass `time.Now()` in real usage and some known time in tests.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Adrian: It's not really fair to say you _can't_ test code that uses the current time. There are strategies for doing so. Having said that, your suggestion is obviously still a good one.

Comment: There are strategies for doing pretty much anything. Just not necessarily *good* strategies...

Comment: @Flimzy, I tried to write unit tests by calling time.Now() in the unit tests. But that won't work and it is expected as well. `time.Now()` in unit test and `time.Now()` in actual function can give different value in seconds. My other idea was to mock the time functionalities as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I am not sure but i won't say it is not possible to write unit test for something. As someone said, `A function which can not tested through unit test is not a function at all `. Just looking for right strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try mocking the time provider and setting up the time.Now() function in your mock to return a preset value which you control. In production you can forward this to a call to the actual time.

Comment: When I'm teaching people about unit testing practices, one of the first things I point out is that the current date/time represents an *external dependency* and has to be mocked. It's a value that you do not control and is constantly changing.

Comment: @DalePalmer I mocked the `time.Now()` through https://github.com/jonboulle/clockwork and it is working fine. Thanks!